# How can I return bitmap from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm tring to receive a bitmap image from web and show it on list view's item which contain image view.
But this seems got a trouble in setting image to Bitmap Object "bmImage".
How can i copy received bitmap and return it?

```
public class DownloadListImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap bmImage;
    public DownloadListImageTask(Bitmap bmImage){
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try{
            InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        bmImage = result.copy(result.getConfig(), true);
    }
}
```

following is a useage

```
Bitmap bitmap;
new DownloadListImageTask(bitmap).execute(url);
adapter.addItem(bitmap);
```

Comment: please have a look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: You should copy in the background thread, not in the post execution.

Comment: thought i got enough information. thx to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the Bitmap `bmImage` in your `AsyncTask` but then you do not return it to the `Activity` that called the `AsyncTask`.

One thing you can do is to create a listener in the AsyncTask:

```
public interface OnBitmapDownloadedListener
{
    void setBitmap(Bitmap bmImage);
}
```

Implement that in the `Activity`

`public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadListImageTask.OnBitmapDownloadListener`

Pass that it into the `AsyncTask` constructor like so:

```
new DownloadListImageTask(bitmap, this).execute(url)
```

Then in `postExecute()` you can call

```
bmImage = result.copy(result.getConfig(), true);
listener.setBitmap(bmImage)
// Do stuff with the bitmap in setBitmap()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a would give all answers what  he needs i believe.